# Lmfit error: The input contains nan values

Tags: python, lmfit

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    """1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"""
    return (amp / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi*wid)) * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2)))

xFull = []
yFull = []

fileTypex = np.dtype([('xFull', np.float)])
fileTypey = np.dtype([('yFull', np.float)])
fDatax = "xValue.dat"
fDatay = "yValue.dat"
xFull = np.loadtxt(fDatax, dtype=fileTypex)
yFull = np.loadtxt(fDatay, dtype=fileTypey)

TailCoreLim1 = 40
TailCoreLim2 = 100 


xCore = xFull[TailCoreLim1:TailCoreLim2]["xFull"]
yCore = yFull[TailCoreLim1:TailCoreLim2]["yFull"]

fileTypeCore = np.dtype([('Par', np.float)])
CoreFile = "CorePopt.dat"
CoreVal = np.loadtxt(CoreFile, dtype=fileTypeCore)
CoreI = CoreVal[0:1]["Par"]
CoreSig = CoreVal[1:2]["Par"]

gmodel = Model(gaussian)
result = gmodel.fit(yCore, x=xCore, amp=1.09054634, cen=0, wid=2.47388884)

plt.plot(xCore, yCore, 'bo')
plt.plot(xCore, result.best_fit, 'r-')

print 'CORE REPORT:'
print 'I1 = ', CoreI
print 'Sigma1 = ', CoreSig
print(result.fit_report())


xTailsx = xFull[0:(TailCoreLim1)]["xFull"]
yTailsx = yFull[0:(TailCoreLim1)]["yFull"]

fileTypeTail = np.dtype([('Par', np.float)])
TailFile = "TailPopt.dat"
TailVal = np.loadtxt(TailFile, dtype=fileTypeTail)
TailI = TailVal[0:1]["Par"]
TailSig = TailVal[1:2]["Par"]

gmodel = Model(gaussian)
result = gmodel.fit(yTailsx, x=xTailsx, amp=1.12567603, cen=0, wid=3.01133102)

plt.plot(xTailsx, yTailsx, 'bo')
plt.plot(xTailsx, result.best_fit, 'r-')

xTaildx = xFull[(TailCoreLim2):140]["xFull"]
yTaildx = yFull[(TailCoreLim2):140]["yFull"]

gmodel = Model(gaussian)
result = gmodel.fit(yTaildx, x=xTaildx, amp=1.12567603, cen=0, wid=3.01133102)

plt.plot(xTaildx, yTaildx, 'bo')
plt.plot(xTaildx, result.best_fit, 'r-')

print 'TAIL REPORT:'
print 'I2 = ', TailI
print 'Sigma2 = ', TailSig
print(result.fit_report())

plt.show()
```

When I run it, it returns me this error: *ValueError: The input contains nan values*, with reference to this line:

```
result = gmodel.fit(yCore, x=xCore, amp=1.09054634, cen=0, wid=2.47388884)
```

Furthermore, if in the definition of the gaussian function, I change the value, then it returns in this way:

```
return (amp / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * wid)) * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2))
```

and I try to run the script, it works without any error.

Could anyone explain me where's the problem please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your example has a lot of extra and unnecessary code in it, that makes it sort of hard to follow.  But, in essence, you are doing (or can easily reduce your code so that you are doing):

```
xFull = np.loadtxt("xValue.dat", dtype=np.float)
yFull = np.loadtxt("yValue.dat", dtype=np.float)

xCore = xFull[40:100]
yCore = yFull[40:100]

gmodel = Model(gaussian)
result = gmodel.fit(yCore, x=xCore, amp=1.09054634, cen=0, wid=2.47388884)
```

The NaNs could be coming because of some very small (near zero) value of `wid`, though I think that is unlikely -- I don't recall ever seeing that.

Or the NaNs could be coming from your data -- I've seen that many times and your code looks very focused on manipulating your data.

So first verify that your data `xCore` and `yCore` do not contain NaNs.  While you're at it, you could plot the data and verify that it is Gaussian-like and that your initial values for `amp`, `cen`, and `wid` are not way off.

If that all looks OK, and you're still getting the NaN ValueError from the fit, print out the values in your `gaussian()` function to try to understand what parameter values are causing the NaNs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the extra parts of the code.
The value of 'wid' I don't think can generate any problem, since it is a fixed value of 2.47 or 3.01. As for the values ​​of xCore and yCore, are a series of numbers whose smaller values ​​are respectively 0.03 and 0.0001, but I don't understand why values ​​very close to 0 should generate NaN errors, would you be so kind to explain it to me? However, I don't think that these values ​​can generate errors, since taking out the square root (in the Gaussian function) the parameter 'wid' all works correctly. Thanks again!

Comment: Please follow the earlier advice.  First, verify there are not nans in your data. I think you may have done this, but you were not explicit (be explicit and clear).  Second, use prints of the parameter values, perhaps data, and perhaps calculated model in your `gaussian` function to find out where the nans are coming from.  NaNs are tricky.  Do not make assumptions about where they cannot be.

Comment: I turned off the PC yesterday, I turn it on today and magically everything seems to work without errors ... Python sometimes scares me ... But thank you again for your help!